# How to dismissPopoverAnimated on iPad with UIPopoverController in MKMapView (SDK3.2)

Tags: iphone, ipad, mkmapview, uipopovercontroller

I have a MKMapView (also a UIPopoverControllerDelegate) with Annotations.  This MapView has, in the **MKTestMapView.h** file, a `UIPopoverController* popoverController` defined in the @interface and a `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController* popoverController;` defined outside of the `@interface` section.  This controller is `@synthesized` in the **MKTestMapView.m** file and it is released in the `- (void)dealloc` section.  The Annotations in this MapView have `rightCalloutAccessoryView`s defined to the following:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView2 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aview calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

...

CGPoint leftTopPoint = [mapView2 convertCoordinate:aview.annotation.coordinate toPointToView:mapView2];

int boxDY=leftTopPoint.y;
int boxDX=leftTopPoint.x;
NSLog(@"\nDX:%d,DY:%d\n",boxDX,boxDY);

popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
popoverController.delegate = self;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f,600.0f);

popoverController.popoverContentSize = maximumLabelSize;

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(boxDX, boxDY, 320.0f, 600.0f);

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];


...

}
```

Now here comes the fun part.  First of all, I am not sure if I need `maximumLabelSize` and the `rect` to be the same size.  I am new to the popovercontroller so I am playing this by ear..

Okay, the popover shows.  Now to dismissing it.  I can click anywhere on mapView2 and the popover goes away...but I need the user to click a button in the view if they change anything.  URGH!

The docs show:

> To dismiss a popover programmatically,
>   call the dismissPopoverAnimated:
>   method of the popover controller.

Well, here is the problem:  By definition of how the popoverController works, you are clicking **inside** the view of the displayed popover (to click the button) but have to trigger the `dismissPopoverAnimated:` method of the controller that **launched** this popover view, in my case, the `popoverController` inside the **MKTestMapView.m** file.

Now, having said all that, remember, `[popoverController release]` doesn't happen until:

```
- (void)dealloc {
 [popoverController release];
 [mapView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

So, do i just do the following inside the button (messy but may work):

(Assuming my popover view is a TableView) In the:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MKTestMapView * mKTestMapView = [[MKTestMapView alloc] init];
[[mKTestMapView popoverController].dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Here is my issue:  I cannot figure out whether doing the above gives me a `reference` (if there is such a thing) to the **existing** view that is on the screen -- and therefore the view that is the owner of that popoverController.  If it is as simple as

```
[[[self parentView] popoverController].dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

I will shoot myself cos I don't think that is the correct syntax either!

This should be easy...yet I am lost.  (probably just frustrated with so many iPad differences that I am learning).

Can anyone explain more?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem... I had a neat "close" button (X) in the top of my view loaded by the popover, but it didn't work. In my universal app it will be presented as a new view, so that code should stay.

What I did now was that I added the following to my detailedPinView (the view the popover loads):

in the detailedPinView.h file:

```
@interface detailedPinView : UIViewController {
    [...]   
    UIPopoverController *popover;
    [...]
}

-(void)setPopover:(UIPopoverController*)aPopover;
```

In the detailedPinView.m file:

```
- (void)setPopover:(UIPopoverController*)aPopover
{
    popover = aPopover;
}
```

The X button closes the view using an IBAction, this is what I did there:

In the detailedPinView.m file:

```
-(IBAction)releaseDetailedView:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if (popover != nil)
        {
            [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Nothing to dismiss");
        }
    }
    else{
        [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    }
}
```

In the class loading the my map and the popover view I added the following code:

```
[...]
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)pin calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{   
    UIViewController *detailController = [[detailedPinView alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailedPinView" 
                                                                           bundle:nil 
                                                                   annotationView:pin];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {

        UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailController];
        [aPopover setDelegate:self];
        [aPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320) animated:YES];

        [detailController setPopover:aPopover];
        [detailController release];

        [mapView deselectAnnotation:pin.annotation animated:YES];

        self.popoverController = aPopover;

        [mapView setCenterCoordinate:pin.annotation.coordinate animated:YES];

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(382,498,0,0) inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self presentModalViewController: detailController animated:YES];
    }


    [detailController release];
}
[...]
```

I don't know if the was the answer you were hoping for, I think it might be a bit of a messy way to do it... but giving the time schedule this worked like a charm :)

Comment: As much as i hate this:

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

because you cannot use it in a Universal App or in a pre-3.2 app, I am gonna mark this as the answer cos this:  [detailController setPopover:aPopover]; is what I needed.

Thx

Comment: Yes, I agree. Didn't had much of a choise given my time schedule but will change it "in the future". Glad I could help!
Regards, Paul

Comment: @Jann "because you cannot use it in a Universal App or in a pre-3.2 app". Yes you can. As long as your Base SDK is 3.2, it will run correctly when deployed on pre-3.2 devices.

Comment: Very useful. This should be the way to dismiss a popover in its own view controller. I use it to implement dismiss a popover by pressing the navigation bar button in the popover.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple solution.

I found that we should follow the following steps for clearly dismissing popovers.

1. dismiss a popover.
2. release a view loaded by the popover.

Before iOS8, almost all of us may release a view loaded by a popover first, and then we programmatically dismiss the popover.
However, in iOS8, we do the steps in revers.

Before iOS8, my code of dismissing a popover

```
// creating a popover loading an image picker
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
...
pickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[pickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:aFrame inView:aView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

// dismissing the popover
[picker.view removeFromSuperview]; // (1) release a view loaded by a popover
[picker release], picker = nil;

if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
    [pickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; // (2) dismiss the popover
}
```

In iOS8, the dismissing code part should be changed as below,

```
if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
    [pickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];  // (2) dismiss the popover first
}

[picker.view removeFromSuperview]; // (1) and then release the view loaded by the popover
[picker release], picker = nil;
```