# Dismissing iPad UIPopoverController from within its content controller

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

So I have a popover with a button in it. When that button is pushed, I want the popover to go away. It seems easy enough, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. The code I use to show the popover is below:

```
    AddCategoryViewController* content = [[AddCategoryViewController alloc] init];
 UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
          initWithContentViewController:content];
 aPopover.delegate = self;
 [content release];

 // Store the popover in a custom property for later use.
 self.addCategoryPopover = aPopover;
 [aPopover release];
 [addCategoryPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Within the addcategoryviewcontroller, I have:

```
    -(IBAction)saveAddCategory:(id)sender {
 if (rootViewController == nil)
  rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

 [rootViewController.addCategoryPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
 [rootViewController dismissPopover];
}
```

Rootviewcontroller is where the popover is being created from. Unfortunately, neither of those methods work to dismiss it. any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be seeing a warning at this line.

```
 aPopover.delegate = self;
```

and if you would execute your code. The app would crash. Instead you need to do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720327/code-is-exectuting-but-the-view-is-not-loading-when-called-form-a-function).

Comment: Note that apple discourages using a button to simply close a popover.

Answer (score 2):

I have

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)anAnimated
{
    [self.dPopover dismissPopoverAnimated: NO];
    self.dPopover = nil;
    [super viewWillDisappear: anAnimated];
}
```

and don't see why this wouldn't work in your case.

Your `if` is a bit troubling, so my guess is you aren't talking to the view you think you are. `rootViewController.addCategoryPopover` is probably nil, because you made a new controller.

Comment: I made that "if" statement pretty much out of desperation as nothing was working for me. I did at one point just try having [rootViewController.addCategoryPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
as the code in that function. That, however, wasn't working either.

Comment: You didn't address my implied question — what is the value of rootViewController.addCategoryPopover?

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered just a similar question with the solution I used to dismiss a popover with a `UIView` loaded from a `MKMapView`. 
The use of my solution is basically the same as for any other view loading a popover.

Have a look at:
[How to dismissPopoverAnimated on iPad with UIPopoverController in MKMapView (SDK3.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639350/how-to-dismisspopoveranimated-on-ipad-with-uipopovercontroller-in-mkmapview-sdk3/2799186#2799186). I hope that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use NSNotificationCenter To DissmissPoperController Fro Father viewControll

Comment: ParentViewController not FatherViewController. One can also use block or delegate or KVO or whatever he wishes.